# Connecting remote mysql via local machine : node expressjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, meanjs

I am trying to connect to remote mysql(hosted on digitalocean server) and using the db for code in local machine.

When I start the node server and request for data, I get the following error.

```
{"ERRORMSG":"Something went wrong.{\"code\":\"ENOTFOUND\",\"errno\":\"ENOTFOUND\",\"syscall\":\"getaddrinfo\",\"hostname\":\"http://ip.of.remote.server/\",\"host\":\"http://ip.of.remote.server/\",\"port\":3306,\"fatal\":true}"}
```

After the first attempt, if I refresh again I get different error

```
{\"code\":\"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR\",\"fatal\":false}
```

Connection is made like this:

```
connection = mysql.createConnection({
    connectionLimit: 10000, //important
    host: 'http://ip.of.remote.server/',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db',
    multipleStatements: true,
    connectionLimit : 100,
    waitForConnections : true,
    queueLimit :0,
    debug    :  true,
    wait_timeout : 28800,
    connect_timeout :10
});
```

Call is made like this

```
app.get('/WSgetdata', function (req, res) {
    var q = "CALL sp_get_data();" 
    var obj = {};
    connection.connect();
    connection.query(q, function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            obj.ERRORMSG = JSON.stringify(err);
        }
        else if((rows[rows.length-1])[0].ERRORSTATUS == 0){
            //do something
        }
        res.end(JSON.stringify(obj))
    });
});
```

What is wrong. It works fine when code and db are on same machine.
Also I have grant access to db from desired IP.

TRACE

```
  Trace
    at Query._callback (d:/project/config\webservice.js:397:25)
at Query.Sequence.end (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
at d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:390:18
at Array.forEach (native)
at d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:389:13
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:336:13)
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://ip.of.remote.server/ http://ip.of.remote.server/:3306]
 code: 'ENOTFOUND',
 errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
 syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
 hostname: 'http://ip.of.remote.server/',
 host: 'http://ip.of.remote.server/',
 port: 3306,
 fatal: true }
 Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://ip.of.remote.server/ http://ip.of.remote.server/:3306
at errnoException (dns.js:25:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:135:48)
at Protocol.handshake (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
at d:/project/config\webservice.js:387:20
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at next (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
at Route.dispatch (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
at Function.proto.process_params (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
Trace
  at Query._callback (d:/project/config\webservice.js:397:25)
at Query.Sequence.end (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:96:24)
at Protocol._validateEnqueue (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:218:6)
at Protocol._enqueue (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:129:13)
at Connection.query (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:197:25)
at d:/project/config\webservice.js:388:20
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at next (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
at Route.dispatch (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
{ [Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.] code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR', fatal: false }
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
at Protocol._validateEnqueue (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:193:16)
at Protocol._enqueue (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:129:13)
at Connection.query (d:/project/node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:197:25)
at d:/project/config\webservice.js:388:20
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at next (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
at Route.dispatch (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
at Function.proto.process_params (d:/project/node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
host: 'http://ip.of.remote.server/',
```

with

```
host: 'ip.of.remote.server',
```

Comment: Have you checked, if you can connect with the mysql cli client or any other tool? Maybe the port is blocked?

Comment: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip.of.remote.server' (10061)